# Finding the visible section and placing a note on top of it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a list of `divs` in a page:

```
<div class="section"><span>Client Information </span>
 <!-- Some fields here -->
</div>
<div class="section"><span>Billing Information </span>
 <!-- Some fields here -->
</div>
<div class="section"><span>Contact Information </span>
 <!-- Some fields here -->
</div>
```

When user scrolls the page I want to a `Note` on top of visible section on the browser.

```
<div class="note">Note:Please fill all the required fields</div>
```

For example

1. When page loads and `Client Infomation` is the visible section. Note should appear on top of Client Information section.
2. User scrolls down and `Billing Information` is the visible section. Note should appear on top of Billing Information section.
3. When user comes down to `Contact Information` section, Note should appear on top on Contact Information section.
4. If user scrolls back to `Client Information` section, note should appear top of Client Information.

> Important 1: Note div should only appear on top of section not overlap section fields.

I tried using

```
.note {
 position:fixed;
 width:100%;
 z-index:1080;
}
```

But this makes note div overlap section fields which I don't.

> Important2: Section divs are below a fixed navigation bar and a logo. In this way when first section is visible. Note div has to be placed between logo and first section.

Comment: What is the problem with `position:fixed`? What should happen when a note and a div collide?

Answer (score 1):

You need some javascript to detect whether the window has scrolled beyond the vertical offset of the note element, and apply the `position:fixed` only then:

http://jsfiddle.net/bSZpf/

Comment: There two issues with your solution.<br/>
1. Nav Bar it self is fixed on top. So Note div hides behind it.
2. `Note div` with `width:100%` does not look good on the page. As Sections are like 60% of the width and in the middle of the page.

Comment: @HimanshuYadav you can adjust the width/padding/positions however you like. I don't know exactly how your page is laid out, but you can adjust the `top` to be little lower to accommodate the navbar.

Also if the navbar is fixed, doesn't it also cover the sections? If so, you can place your 'note' inside the navbar.

What I'm demonstrating is just a general concept of what is usually done in instances similar to yours.